# Putting a button inside a collapsing card in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put a button in a collapse (part of an accordion) that will go to a new page when clicked. But right now when I try to click the button, it instead just closes the collapse.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header p-1">
      <a class="card-link stretched-link text-body" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-8 pl-1"><strong>Title </strong></div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-right"><span class="badge badge-danger p-1">High Priority</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                    <!-- Lock this to prevent word wrap from too mane names -->
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1">Name</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1">Name</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning mr-1">Name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body p-1">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-9">

                    <div class="row  m-0 p-0 ">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col text-center">
                                    <small><strong>Start:</small></strong><br>30 May 08:00
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center">
            <small><strong>Late/Expire:</small></strong><br>30 Jun 16:00
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <small><strong>Category</small></strong><br>Catering
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <small><strong>Reward:</small></strong><br>300
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- Here is the button I can't seem to click -->
<div class="col-3 p-1 align-self-center"><a href="active_chore.php?todo_id=242" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><strong>View Chore</strong></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Oddly enough, when I put the snippet and run it on stack overflow, it works fine. But when I run it in my browser, clicking anywhere in the card-body hides the collapse element.

Thanks for the help
Seth

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found it. The "stretched-link" in the card header is making the whole card, including the body a stretched-link. For some reason the stack overflow snippet doesn't do that but the Chrome browser does.